# Passing variables to custom formtypes to be used in twig templates

Tags: php, symfony, variables, types, twig

I have a custom form type I'm using to render a drag and drop image uploader in my form. It's to add files to a `listing` object and so if the user comes back to the `listing` object to update it or if they refresh the page, I'd like to be able to display the files they've already uploaded.

**ListingController.php**

```
/**
 * @Route("/account/listings/update/{id}", name="listing_update", requirements={"id": "\d+"})
 * @ParamConverter("listing", class="DirectoryPlatform\AppBundle\Entity\Listing")
 */
public function updateAction(Request $request, Listing $listing)
{
    $existingFiles = $this->get('punk_ave.file_uploader')->getFiles(array('folder' => 'tmp/attachments/' . $listing->getId()));
    if ($this->getUser() !== $listing->getUser()) {
        throw $this->createAccessDeniedException('You are not allowed to access this page.');
    }

    $form = $this->createForm(ListingType::class, $listing, [
        'currency' => $this->getParameter('app.currency'),
        'hierarchy_categories' => new Hierarchy($this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Category'), 'category', 'categories'),
        'hierarchy_locations' => new Hierarchy($this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Location'), 'location', 'locations'),
    ]);
    $form->handleRequest($request);


    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        /** @var Listing $listing */
        $listing = $form->getData();

        try {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($listing);

            /** @var Image $image */
            foreach ($listing->getImages() as $image) {
                if (empty($image->getImageName())) {
                    $em->remove($image);
                }
            }

            $em->flush();
            $this->addFlash('success', $this->get('translator')->trans('Listing has been successfully saved.'));
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->addFlash('danger', $this->get('translator')->trans('An error occurred when saving listing object.'));
        }

        return $this->redirectToRoute('listing_update', ['id' => $listing->getId()]);
    }

    return $this->render('FrontBundle::Listing/update.html.twig', [
        'listing' => $listing,
        'editId' => $listing->getId(),
        'existingFiles' => $existingFiles,
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ]);
}
```

The variable in question is `$existingFiles` which I'm attempting to pass in the `render()` method so they can be displayed in the twig

**dropzone.html.twig**

```
{% block dropzone_widget %}
<div class="{{ class }}">

    {% for file in existingFiles %}
    <img src="/uploads/tmp/attachments/{{ listing.getId }}/large/{{ file }}">
    {% endfor %}
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

**DropzoneType.php**

```
<?php
namespace DirectoryPlatform\FrontBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\FormType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormView;

class DropZoneType extends AbstractType
{
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        // default form options
        'class' => 'file-uploader'
        ));
    }

    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return "dropzone";
    }
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form, array $options)
    {
        $view->vars['class'] = $options['class'];
    }
        public function getParent()
    {
        return FormType::class;
    }
}
```

But I'm getting an error `Variable "existingFiles" does not exist.`

Edit: Including my config.yml

**config.yml**

```
# Twig Configuration
twig:
    debug: '%kernel.debug%'
    strict_variables: '%kernel.debug%'
    form_themes:
      - 'AppBundle:Form:bootstrap.html.twig'
      - 'AppBundle:Form:collection.html.twig'
      - 'AppBundle:Form:dropzone.html.twig'
    globals:
        google_maps_api_key: "%google_maps_api_key%"
        google_analytics_code: "%google_analytics_code%"
        enable_registration: "%enable_registration%"
```

Comment: how is dropzone.html.twig included in your template?

Comment: I included it in config.yml in form_themes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have a DropZoneType form type and (I guess) you have added it as a child  to your ListingType form type, you can pass it like an option like this:

1. Pass the existing files as option from the controller to the ListingType:

   ```
   // ListingController.php

   $form = $this->createForm(ListingType::class, $listing, [
       'currency' => $this->getParameter('app.currency'),
       'hierarchy_categories' => new Hierarchy($this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Category'), 'category', 'categories'),
       'hierarchy_locations' => new Hierarchy($this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Location'), 'location', 'locations'),
       'existingFiles' => $existingFiles
   ]);
   ```
2. Pass the existing files as option from the ListingType to the DropzoneType:

   ```
   // ListingType.php

   public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
   {
       $existingFiles = $options['existingFiles'];

       $builder
           ...
           ->add('dropzone', DropZoneType::class, [
               // other options          
              'existingFiles' => $existingFiles
           ]);
   }
   ```
3. Get your existing files in DropZoneType and set it as form view variable:

   ```
   // DropZoneType.php
   public function buildView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form, array $options)
   {
       $view->vars['class'] = $options['class'];
       $view->vars['existingFiles'] = $options['existingFiles'] ?? []; // in case no existing files are given
   }
   ```

Then you can render them in your dropzone.html.twig as you currently do.

Comment: I did it as you said but I'm getting a different error now that's `Notice: Undefined variable: existingFiles` in `ListingType.php`, you are right though, DropZoneType is a child to ListingType. I also in addition to your suggestion, added `existingFiles => null` to `setDefaults` in `ListingType`

Comment: Could you debug the value of $existingFiles under the $existingFiles = $options['existingFiles']; line in ListingType?

Comment: Actually, you're right, I just forgot `$existingFiles = $options['existingFiles'];` in the `ListingType.php`